# Auto enter pass phrase in case of Python ssl Client/Server

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, certificate

I need to create Client/Server application to send files from clients to Server.
I use simple ssl sockets for that and authenticate with certificates.

```
 
ms = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(ms,
                           keyfile=".../newCA/my_client.key",
                           certfile=".../newCA/my_client.crt",
                           server_side=0,
                           cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                           ca_certs=".../newCA/CA/my-ca.crt"
                           )
ssl_sock.connect((HOST, MPORT))
```

And Server side:

```
msock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(msock,
                           keyfile=".../newCA/my_server.key",
                           certfile=".../newCA/my_server.crt",
                           server_side=1,
                           cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                           ca_certs=".../newCA/CA/my-ca.crt"
                           )
        self.ssl_sock.bind(('', self.PORT))
        self.ssl_sock.listen(self.QUEUE_MAX)
```

The problem is the following: when client tries to connect to Server, it requires Enter the pass phrase for private key for Both: for Server-side and Client-side.

- In Java we need to set System Property: javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="" and it has to be used automatically, But how is it been used in Python? I can't enter pass phrase all time the client connects.

---

The problem is that my Application:Client should use already signed certificate, and Server should use already signed certificate too. I can't change it. Both Serever and Clients are long-living applications, so we just run it and we no need to look for them. But, as I understand, Python doesn't provide statndard way to automatically enter pass phrase for private key. May be other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pass phrase is meant to be entered by a human as means of identification. If you want to hardcode it, a SSL key without passphrase provides the same level of security.
For getting rid of the pass phrase, see also: https://web.archive.org/web/20090116084124/http://www.aleph-null.tv/article/20080714-1337-917.xml/Apache,-SSL,-and-&quot%3BGetting-Rid-of-the-Passphrase&quot%3B

Comment: Removing the passphrase does not change the validity of the signature of the certificate. It's a simple outer encryption layer, and can be removed without re-signing.

Comment: The link is dead as of today, 09/21/2020

Comment: @susenj thanks, I've replaced the link with an archived one from the wayback machine

Answer (score 5):

You can refer to [SSLSocket passphrase/password in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688713/sslsocket-passphrase-password-in-python) as well. It is valid to remove the passphrase of the private key file for the server side case. OpenSSL provides utils to do that. 
For example:

`openssl pkey -in yourkey-with-pass.pem -out yourkey-without-pass.pem`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that I found by taking inspiration from this article:
[Creating a Python requests session using a passphrase protected Client side Cert](https://gist.github.com/aiguofer/1eb881ccf199d4aaa2097d87f93ace6a)

```
import ssl
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

class SSLAdapter(HTTPAdapter):

    def init_poolmanager(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
        context.load_cert_chain(certfile='my_certificate.crt',
                                password='my_passphrase')
        kwargs['ssl_context'] = context
        return super().init_poolmanager(*args, **kwargs)

session = requests.session()
session.mount('https://my_protected_site.com', SSLAdapter())
```

Comment: this helped me for my Flask server running with gevent PyWSGI: `context = SSLContext(ssl_version=PROTOCOL_SSLv23);
context.load_cert_chain(certfile='path/to/my_ssl.crt', keyfile='path/to/my_ssl.key', password='enterPasswordHere'); http_server = WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', port), main.app, ssl_context=context); http_server.serve_forever()`