# SSLSocket passphrase/password in Python

Tags: python, ios, ssl, python-2.7, push-notification

I've been looking into making an iOS push notification service for one of my apps lately. It has a Python 2.7 backend so I wanted to do it in Python rather than PHP (or anything else).

I've got code that sends a notification and the device receives it, however every time I run the code it asks me to manually enter a 'pass phrase' for the PEM file.

This is not ideal, as I want this to be all automated on the server, when it needs to send a notification, it should just send it. I can't find anything in the docs for Python 2.7 that allow me to automatically set the pass phrase from a variable when connecting.

If anyone knows how to do this in Python 2.7 or any other ideas I would be really grateful.

Here's a snippet of code:

```
certfile = 'devPEM.pem'
apns_address = ('gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com', 2195)

s = socket.socket()
sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3, certfile=certfile)
sock.connect(apns_address)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you generated the .pem certificate... Did you give it a password? Because if so, that's probably what it's asking you about

Comment: @BorrajaX Yeah I did and I know what the password is. Should you be able to create the .pem without a password because I thought it wouldn't let me make it without it?

Comment: yeah, I don't know how it is done in iOS, but you should be able to give it a blank password (just press enter when prompted for it). Let me know if it works **:-)**

Comment: So creating it through the terminal on a mac it asks for the password to be min 4 char. I managed to remove the password from the cert with <code>openssl rsa -in privateKey.pem -out newPrivateKey.pem<code> . That seams to work but it takes ages to produce a notification on a device. :(

Comment: Strike that, the first one seemed to be a fluke. Later ones are practically instant. :D

Comment: I removed passphrase, but still I am getting following error : 
SSLError: [Errno 336445449] _ssl.c:353: error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib
how to resolve this ?

Comment: Above error is coming in case of python2.6.Also,I am getting error with python2.7.9 as follows : 
 File "E:\Python27\push.py", line 41, in <module>
    send_push(TOKEN, json.dumps(PAYLOAD))
  File "E:\Python27\push.py", line 28, in send_push
    sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3, certfile=cert)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 891, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 509, in __init__
    self._context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2506)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So the answer as BorrajaX suggested was to not set a password for the key when prompted. However this is not possible as (at least on my Mac) wants the password to be a minimum 4 characters.

The steps to fix this are:

1. Create the certificate in the developer portal.
2. Download and open the certificate locally in Keychain Access
3. Export the certificate’s private key as a .p12 file from Keychain Access (I named it aps_key.p12).
4. Run the following on the .p12 key:
   `openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out aps_key.pem -in aps_key.p12`
5. Enter a password (which we will strip in a minute).
6. Run the following to strip the password:
   `openssl rsa -in aps_key.pem -out new_aps_key.pem`
7. Convert the .cer downloaded from the Developer Center to a .pem file:
   `openssl x509 -in aps.cer -inform der -out aps.pem`
8. Merge the key and certificate .pem files with the following:
   `cat aps.pem new_aps_key.pem > final_aps.pem`
9. You can now delete all other files, except for `final_aps.pem`.

The `final_aps.pem` file then works with the code above without getting prompted for a password/pass phrase.

This is a useful website where I found the code for removing the password from the .pem file: http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html

Edit: If you don't need the certificate and the key in the same file, you can just ignore step 8 and use the `aps.pem` and `new_aps_key.pem` files.