# How can I send a push notification without prompting the password each time?

Tags: python, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using the `apns` library to send push notifications to my iPhone. While I'm successfully receiving push notifications to my device, the script asks for the Certificate password every time I run it to send a push notification. I'm trying to figure out a way to include the password somehow in the code but have been unsuccessful so far.

I'm running the example code from their repository:

```
from apns import APNs, Payload

apns = APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file='TestCert.pem', key_file='TestKey.pem')

# Send a notification
token_hex = '<token hidden for obvious reasons>'
payload = Payload(alert="Hello World!", sound="default", badge=1)
apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)
```

I've also been checking the library [source code](https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs/blob/master/apns.py) but it doesn't seem to have any useful option.

Comment: Since [Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ssl.html) there is a function that includes a password for a given certificate, unfortunately I'm using Python 2.7. Maybe the only possible solution is regenerating the certificate with an option to avoid requiring password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a decent solution on the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688713/sslsocket-passphrase-password-in-python).

I've also found out that from Python 3.3 it's possible to use the password adding the method `SSLContext.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile, password)` in the function that opens the SSL connection.